# Magento Custom Product Consulting forum with add to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I am looking a solution for consulting clients. They sell services. We want to create a product where a user first fill a form and then choose how much question he want to ask. 
We will charge him based to No of Question

Can someone Give me any idea how we can do this in Magento??

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I would add custom options `No of questions` and add a fee for each question.

Then you need to think, how to add the questions. One way is to add another custom option which is just a text area.

Or you add some JS, make a (+) button to add a new input field. Then you can even hide the first custom option and adjust it by the questions

Answer (score -2):

you can use quantity as a question, or you can sell your services as per hour charge in magento.

Comment: Yes its fine. but we want Input from users his details then he select quantity and fill the box regarding details

Comment: you have to make customize here for before add service to cart .you have to fill form of detail and than add quantity product page.